# How to add text in PowerPivot Table or other alternative

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I need to add text columns in a PowerPivot Table, I have read a lot of sources that said it is not possible because it needs to be aggregation and I saw some instructions on having a "lookup" column or something. Unfortunately this would not work on my end because of the dynamic values I am expecting to get (ID, Project Name, Manager Name etc.) I saw one that uses VBA but he didn't go to explain his process.

My second alternative I thought of is using ordinary table with PowerQuery, the problem I have on this one is the grouping of projects. Because the format they want is a concatenation of Program Name and Project Name which looks like this: 
[image]

Which is easily can be done on PowerPivot Table but limitation exist that I can't put text columns on it.

Edit: My wanted final output would more or less look like  this
[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want your end result to look like?

Comment: What is the source of the ID and Manager? Are they another table?

Comment: All of them are on the same table

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to return a text measure.

For example if I were to define a measure as,

```
Manager:= IF ( HASONVALUE( table1[Manager] ), VALUES( table1[Manager] ), BLANK() )
```

It would return the manager only when the row has a single manager, else it would return and empty result.

Comment: What do you mean by single manager? Like it only supports one type of manager?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by changing the Report Layout to Tabular Form (PivotTable Tools -> Design)

After a lot of experimentation I found a way to make the hierarchy by doing this:

My first 2 rows is Program Manager then Project Name

For the Program Manager, I edited the layout to:

[image]

While the Project Name is: 
"Show items labels in tabular form"

This way it will stack like above and then I put more text type fields after that which work.